# Position sticky element under parent of overflow-x: auto

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table which has `overflow-x: auto` to show horizontal scroll bar. I am trying to make my header row sticky on `browser scroll`, I've tried putting `position: sticky` to `th` elements but it didn't work and I found out the solution could be to put sticky to `body` and not to the parent element. So I remove from parent and put sticky to body and now my header row is sticky but the scroll bar is not in the table anymore and because of overflow-x: auto to body, everything messed up. Are there any workarounds that I can make my header row sticky and see the scrollbar inside table ?
Here is the sample of my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stick-header-row-d6m7j?file=/src/MakeTable.jsx)

Comment: I posted a code sandbox sample https://codesandbox.io/s/stick-header-row-d6m7j?file=/src/MakeTable.jsx, I will try to add some of my codes on post as well.